# Infer template type of lambda in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, generic-programming

I have to following class:

```
template<typename T>
class SafeCallback
{
public:
    typedef std::function<T> FunctionType;
    SafeCallback(std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid, FunctionType callback)
        : is_valid_(is_valid), callback_(callback)
    {
    }

    template <class ...Arg>
    void operator()(Arg&&... parameters)
    {
        if ((*is_valid_) == true)
        {
            callback_(std::forward<Arg>(parameters)...);
        }
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid_;
    FunctionType callback_;
};
```

To construct such an object with a lambda as the callback I can do something like this:

```
SafeCallback<void(int)>(guard, [] (int value) { /* Do sthing */ });
```

But I would imagine that there should be a way for C++ to infer the type arguments of `SafeCallback` using a factory method. If I create such a method:

```
template<typename T>
SafeCallback<T> makeSafe(std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid, std::function<T> callback)
{
    return SafeCallback<T>(is_valid, callback);
}
```

But this doesnt work with lambdas, only if I pass a `std::function`. Any ideas?

Comment: Things get messy with deducing template parameters in `std::function`. Try using `T` as `FunctionType` in `SafeCallback` and `callback` in `makeSafe`. This way, the function type is automatically deduced.

Comment: I already tried that. When I do this i get `no known conversion for argument 1 fro.m ‘SafeCallback<Consumer::registerToProducer(Producer*)::__lambda0>’ to ‘SafeCallback<std::function<void(int)> ` so it seems to have trouble converting the lambda to the right std::function

Comment: Why store a `std::function` at all?  Why not just an `F`?

Comment: Well since I might also want to call member-methods in `SafeCallback` using std::bind.

Answer (score 5):

Don't type erase needlessly.  Instead, store the raw `F`, and provide conversion to compatible other `SafeCallback`s:

```
template<typename F>
class SafeCallback {
public:
  // helper alias.  `compatible<O>` is `void` iff O is compatible
  // with initializing an `F`.  If not, it is a SFINAE failure.
  template<class O>
  using compatible=std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<O,F>::value>;

  // Construct from an arbitrary `T` with perfect forwarding:
  template<class T, class=compatible<T>>
  SafeCallback(std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid, T&& callback):
    is_valid_(is_valid),
    callback_(std::forward<T>(callback))
  {}

  // invoke, non-`const` version:
  template <class ...Arg>
  void operator()(Arg&&... parameters) {
    if ((*is_valid_) == true) {
      callback_(std::forward<Arg>(parameters)...);
    }
  }
  // invoke, `const` version:
  template <class ...Arg>
  void operator()(Arg&&... parameters)const {
    if ((*is_valid_) == true) {
      callback_(std::forward<Arg>(parameters)...);
    }
  }

  // explicit copy and move ctors:
  SafeCallback(SafeCallback const& o)=default;
  // in MSVC you'll have to write this one in 2 lines:
  SafeCallback(SafeCallback && o)=default;
  // and write `operator=(&&)` in MSVC as well.

  // copy from a compatible SafeCallback<O>:
  template<class O, class=compatible<O const&>>
  SafeCallback(SafeCallback<O> const& o):
    is_valid_(o.is_valid_),
    callback_(o.callback_)
  {}
  // copy from a compatible SafeCallback<O> rvalue:
  template<class O, class=compatible<O>>
  SafeCallback(SafeCallback<O> && o):
    is_valid_(std::move(o.is_valid_)),
    callback_(std::move(o.callback_))
  {}
  // efficient operator= optional: conversion will work if you
  // don't bother I think?
private:
  std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid_;
  F callback_;
  // ensure our siblings can access our privates:
  template<class O>
  friend class SafeCallback;
};
```

now we get:

```
// the F_v is just a way to introduce a new derived type
// for storage -- DRY optimization:
template<class F, class F_v=std::decay_t<F>>
SafeCallback<F_v>
makeSafe(std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid, F&& callback) {
  return SafeCallback<F_v>(is_valid, std::forward<F>(callback));
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e1e487d375827da).

If you want to store your `SafeCallback` in a non-type deduced context, you'll want to type the type out manually.  If you are in a type-deduced context, why erase the type information?  That costs efficiency.

Plus, the above supports variardic and `auto` lambdas.  Which are coming down the pipe everywhere.

Note that the SFINAE support may or may not work in MSVC, but it isn't crucial (the `class=compatible` clauses).  In addition, I used `_t` aliases for a few `std::` traits -- replace `blah_t<?>` with `typename blah<?>::type` if your std library lacks them.  Next, note that the tests to convert to `std::function` are going to not work SFINAE, as `std::function` has some crappy ctors that are overly greedy.  I expect a future iteration of the standard will fix that.

`std::function` is **not** a 'general purpose container for storing all kinds of callables' -- it is a type erasure mechanism to erase almost everything *except* the fact that it is callable.  You type erase when you want to throw out information about a type.

It is very, very rarely a good idea to type erase based on the properties of the incoming type to be erased.  If you want the output type to be dependent on the input type, usually using the input type is better than extracting one part of it.  If you want it to be independent, it means that the code was written independent of the input type, and you want to *match* for compatibility, not *extract* properties and erase all but the extracted ones.

Finally, I find safe callbacks that depend on a `std::weak_ptr<void>` to be best.  The source object provides a `std::shared_ptr<?>` (maybe a pointer to `this`, maybe to a token that `this` holds) that it guarantees will live as long as the class itself.  In `SafeCallback` you `if (auto _ = is_valid_.lock())` to see if the target is still alive.

There is still a race condition or reentrancy danger, but it handles a lot of issues.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer! Thats what I was looking for. Can you maybe recommend something that can help me understandstuff like type deduction, SFINAE and in general more advanced template programing. Also could you maybe elaborate on the `std::function` stuff you mentioned? I dont really understand that point... But anyway: Thanks so much again!

Comment: @matej try googling some of those keywords?  I am not sure if a comprehensive source for this kind of thing exists, as that is not how I picked it up.  I know of books that cover the basics?

Answer (score 2):

lambda is not an exact match to `std::function<T>` and so `T` cannot be deduced.

**Edit**: (Remove previous wrong answer)

You may use `decltype` to get type of `operator()` of the lambda and rebuild the type with a helper:

```
template <typename T> struct helper : helper<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename Ret, typename C, typename ... Args>
struct helper<Ret (C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = Ret(Args...);
};

template<typename T>
SafeCallback<typename helper<T>::type>
makeSafe(std::shared_ptr<bool> is_valid, T callback)
{
    return SafeCallback<typename helper<T>::type>(is_valid, callback);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49376ee28d924f86)

That requires that the functor (your lambda) doesn't have several overload of `operator()`.

Comment: That one only works for functors, not regular functions.

Comment: Your `makeSafe` [doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59ecf33be3a5be02).